# How can my JUnit test connect to my Spring Service?

Tags: spring, junit

I have a Spring application built, like this ...

JSP -> MyController -> MyService -> MyDAO -> TheDatabase

Works great.

Now I want to build a JUnit test to exercise the MyService ... do creates, edits, delete, for santity testing functionality.

I created a JUnit 4 class in my src/test/java/com/mycompany/myapp folder, I run the server, and then I try to run the test.

But it fails because the @Autowired MyService is not getting instantiated.

```
public class Test1 {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        myService.doSomething();

    }

}
```

QUESTION: How do I get Spring to instantiate the MyService in my JUnit test?

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testing ?

Answer (score 1):

By adding the following annotations to your test class/dependencies (spring-test) to your project:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(/*...*/)
```

The server will not be needed/involved at (test) runtime.
And of course additional studies, as proposed by dunni's comment, might help!

=> http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testing